# Accessing a variable list through a class instance object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I currently develop an SDK and I want to know how to access a list of variables through a class instance object as follow:

```
MyClass * myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];

[myObject changeShape : myObject.FORM_SQUARE];
[myObject changeShape : myObject.FORM_CIRCLE];
[myObject changeShape : myObject.FORM_RECTANGLE];
...
```

These variables ( three dozen ) are static and return just an integer to identify the form.

Do I have to set a `@property` for each variable or may be there are a more optimized way?

Answer (score 0):

If they are not properties then you will have to implement a getter method to access them.

```
-(String*)getiVar{
     return iVar;
}
```

Comment: "Getter" methods in Objective-C/Swift do not use the `get` naming prefix. The method would simply be named `iVar`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution is to use NS_ENUM.

Like that:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, shape) {

rectangle = 0,
triangle = 1,
square = 1,
    ...    
};

-(void)changeShape:(shape)newShape;
```